# Как отправить xml через сокеты правильно?

Tags: android, xml, сокет

Я подключаюсь к старому серверу через сокеты, и отсылаю ему xml файл. Сервер должен отсылать свой xml(весьма не больших размеров) , и в отправке этого xml загвоздка.

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(Server);

Socket s = new Socket(serverAddr, Port);
```

Отправляю вот так :

```
            XmlSerializer xmlcreate = Xml.newSerializer();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            xmlcreate.setOutput(writer);

            //Start Document
            xmlcreate.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
            xmlcreate.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);
            //Open Tag <Command>
            xmlcreate.startTag("", "Command");


        // Отправка параметра
            xmlcreate.startTag("","Type");
            xmlcreate.text("SERVER_CONNECTION");
            xmlcreate.endTag("","Type");

            // Отправка параметра
            xmlcreate.startTag("","Timeout");
            xmlcreate.text("5");
            xmlcreate.endTag("","Timeout");
            //__________________________________________

            // Параметры
            xmlcreate.startTag("","Parameter");

            xmlcreate.startTag("","string");

            xmlcreate.text("admin");

            xmlcreate.endTag("","string");

            xmlcreate.startTag("","string");

            xmlcreate.text("MobileInventory");
        //    xmlcreate.text("1");

            xmlcreate.endTag("","string");

            xmlcreate.startTag("","string");

            xmlcreate.text("\\Program Files\\MobileInventory\\config.xml");

            xmlcreate.endTag("","string");


            xmlcreate.endTag("","Parameter");

            //__________________________________________

            xmlcreate.startTag("","TermCode");

            xmlcreate.text(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            xmlcreate.endTag("","TermCode");

            //close Tag <Command>
            xmlcreate.endTag("", "Command");
            xmlcreate.endDocument();


 //XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            //Отправляем на сервер xml
            DataOutputStream serverOutput = new 
 DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            serverOutput.writeChars(writer.toString());           

            serverOutput.flush();
```

Сервер не получаем этот xml. Что Я  делаю не так?

Я не работал с сетевыми прогами, и я совсем не понимаю что мне делать в этой ситуации. pls help

p.s. сервер написан на сокетах и на c#, не мой и кода у меня нет его

Comment: Если поток зависает на попытке чтения, значит он ждёт данные - то есть у вас данные не пришли. Подозреваю что вы открыли сокет, отправили свой пакет, потом открыли другой и ждёте ответа, но ответ отправлен в первый. В общем для всей сессии общения с сервером нужно использовать один экземпляр сокета.

Comment: @woesss Я использую один экземпляр сокета

Comment: А отправка на сервер своего файла работает? Сервер успешно получает? Как отправляете?

Comment: @justcvb вроде успешно работает, код добавил

Comment: @justcvb упс ошибочка- мы походу даже не правильно отправляем данные серверу - Я достучался до автора, и он не делает того, чтро делает при получении команды на коннетк... Меняю вопрос

Comment: @woesss правильные замечания)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в кодировке:

```
serverOutput.writeUTF(writer.toString());
serverOutput.flush();
```

Comment: Тут фокус в другом - `writeUTF` записывает длину текста, а потом сам текст. Значит на той стороне используется обратный метод `readUTF` - он неправильно определял размер текста и благополучно зависал, потому что размер вы ему не передавали.